# What does "idiomatic for what we say..." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

You say this to ask for something that you have chosen in a restaurant or shop

- *I’ll have a T-bone steak and chips, please*.

> A: What does "have" in the sentence above mean?

> B:  It's **idiomatic for what we say to the waiter**.
>
> - I'll have a steak.
> - I would like a steak.
> - I'd like to order a steak.

[Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i%E2%80%99ll-have-a-t-bone-steak-and-chips-please.3823999/#post-19537714)

---

I'm having trouble understanding the bold part.
What exactly does the bold part mean?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you look up 'idiomatic' in a dictionary? if so, what don't you understand?

Comment: It is a typical, natural thing for a person ordering a meal to say.

Comment: @KateBunting: I don't find OP's *exact* cited phrasing "natural, idiomatic". To my ear, ***idiomatic*** is an adjective, and it doesn't sit well in a construction where I'd normally expect a ***noun***. Suppose the utterance being queried was ***You there! Gimmie a steak and chips**!*  So far as I'm concerned, it wouldn't be very good for B to reply ***It's rude for what we say to a waiter***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that the quoted sentence is badly expressed - but the OP asked "What does it mean?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a very well expressed sentence.

Compare with " 'Merci' **is French for** thankyou." That means that *merci* is the word or expression in the French language that means the same as 'thankyou' in English"

By analogy "It's idiomatic for what we say to a waiter 'I would like a steak'..." Can be understood as "'I'll have a steak' is the expression in idiomatic language that means the same as 'I would like a steak'".

The author is saying that "I'll have ..." is an idiomatic expression, and it means the same as "I would like ..."

But the analogy doesn't work very well, because "French" can function as the name of a language, but "idiomatic" isn't the name of a language.  So this is not a good example of clear English.